# Project not loading in VS2013

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

After merging a few branches and the corresponding solution file , one of my project is not loaded and I receive the follow message "The project file has been moved renamed or not on your computer"

I'm using VS2013 , and the corresponding project exists on the hard drive, and was loaded successfully before the merge.

Comment: Project and Solution files are 2 separate files. Do you still have the *.*proj file?

Comment: yes it is still there

Comment: Make a diff of before and after the merge of these 2 files, and bisect to see where it went wrong. You are right to suspect the merge.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in the solution file there was problem with the individual projects identifiers

What I ended up doing is

1. Removing the unloaded project
2. Creating a new temp project
3. Adding the unloaded project
4. Removing the temp project